# JS Mouse action eventListeners (mousever, mouseleave, click) working individually but not together

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, addeventlistener

I'm building a Chrome extension. Its popup window has a logo banner that I want to double as a pause/activate button for my extension. Background color of this banner indicates if the extension is currently active.

The banner is a div with id 'pophead' and I'm putting 3 event listeners on it.

- 'mouseover' => check if the extension is currently active and change the content of the div to pause or activate
- 'mouseleave' => display the correct pophead banner - active or passive
- 'click' => check if the extension is currently active and change the variable in chrome.storage accordingly

PROBLEM:
I can't get all 3 to work together. Individually or 2 at a time work fine, the callbacks do what they need to do, but when all 3 are applied...

- 'click' callback never triggers
- 'mouseleave' only seems to work when the mouse moves out through top or bottom, not left or right of the div
- it works when the callbacks are just alerts or console.logs but not when they need to do something

I am at my wits end... thanks for your help!

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PopUp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup2.css">
</head>

<body>
        <div id="pophead">
            <div><img src="imgs/Eclipser_logo.png" id="logo" class="shadow"></div>  
            <div id="tagline" class="shadow"> FOCUS IS A SUPERPOWER! </div>
        </div>

    <script src="popup.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {     
    
    //Eclipser active?
    let active;  // stores if Eclipser is currently active
    chrome.storage.sync.get('eclipser_all', function (result) {
        active = result.eclipser_all;
    });

    //  Pophead versions
    let pophead_active = `
    <div><img src="imgs/Eclipser_logo.png" id="logo" class="shadow"></div>  
        <div id="tagline" class="shadow"> FOCUS IS A SUPERPOWER! </div>
    `
    let pophead_passive = `
    <div><img src="imgs/Eclipser_logo.png" id="logo" class="shadow"></div>  
        <div id="tagline" class="shadow"> PAUSED </div>
    `
    let pophead_pause = `
    <div><img src="imgs/pause.png" id="logo" class="shadow"></div>  
        <div id="tagline" class="shadow"> PAUSE </div>
    `
    let pophead_activate = `
    <div><img src="imgs/play.png" id="logo" class="shadow"></div>   
        <div id="tagline" class="shadow"> ACTIVATE! </div>
    `
    
    // Pophead events
    const pophead = document.getElementById('pophead');
    setPophead(); // display correct pophead on load

    pophead.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        if(active){
                pophead.innerHTML=pophead_pause;
                pophead.style.backgroundColor='var(--dark_green)'
            }else if(!active){
                pophead.innerHTML=pophead_activate;
            }
    });
    
    pophead.addEventListener('mouseleave', setPophead);
    
    pophead.addEventListener('click',() => {
        alert('clicked');
        chrome.storage.sync.get('eclipser_all', function (result) {
            if(result.eclipser_all == false){
                chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'eclipser_all': true }, ()=>setPophead);
                active=true;
                console.log('Eclipser Activated');
            }else if(result.eclipser_all == true){
                chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'eclipser_all': false }, ()=>setPophead);
                active=false;
                console.log('Eclipser Paused');
            }
            setPophead();
        });
    },false);

    // display correct pophead
    function setPophead(){
        chrome.storage.sync.get('eclipser_all', function (result) {
            if(result.eclipser_all == false){
                pophead.innerHTML=pophead_passive;
                pophead.style.backgroundColor='grey';
            }else{
                pophead.innerHTML=pophead_active;
                pophead.style.backgroundColor='green';
            }
        });
    }
});
```

popup.css

```
body{
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #fff;  
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: gray;
}

#pophead{
    width: 250px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: var(--green);
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center
    
}

#logo{
    max-width:150px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 10px 10px 6px 10px;
}

#tagline{
    width:100%;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 10pt;
}

.shadow{
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 8px grey);
}
```

Comment: Seems like the DOM manipulation are braking the `mouseleave` event. If you avoid them, all the 3 are working - https://jsbin.com/diyapituwi/edit?html,js,output. I wonder why you need to **change the DOM** on mouseover. Can't you achieve the same effect with css?

Comment: You are right! I should have thought of that. Thanks

Comment: Let me know if you need more help with that..